# Is there a save point before fighting Bonetail in the Pit of 100 Trials?

Tags: paper-mario-the-thousand-year-door

I've almost fully completed *Paper Mario: The Thousand Year Door*, with only the final optional boss fight with Bonetail to go.

However, he is at the bottom of the Pit of 100 Trials, which means you have to slog through 99 battles in order to get to him (more or less, as randomly you are able to skip a few levels).  Regardless, I am not eager to spend all the time getting to Bonetail, only to lose to him, which would force me to repeat the entire process.

I've been down to level 50 of the Pit and have not found a single save box.  Is there a save box right before the last level?

Comment: Always wondered this myself...

Comment: (In fact the pit is somewhat overnamed: there are only 91 trials including bonetail, because levels which are multiples of ten but less than one hundred are the reprieves. And the movers can help you skip levels too.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope - no saving is what makes the Pit so darn tricky.

Comment: That's always the point of this sort of thing, after all... :)